# Flutter Android app crashes on startup with no errors

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an Android app that was built with Flutter. I previously encountered this error

```
[Dependency failing: com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:7.7 -> net.minidev:json-smart@[1.3.1,2.3]][1]
```

for which I applied [this workaround](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1676#issuecomment-441243419):

```
 // Bottom of android/app/build.gradle
 com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

It does not seem to be an ideal workaround but at least it bypasses the error.

The project has been migrated to AndroidX according to [instructions](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility).

However now on debug, the launch screen opens but the app crashes straight away. The only console errors are:

```
 registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
 registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
 registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
 Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.

 [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.7.8+hotfix.4, on Mac OS X 10.14.4 18E226, locale en-US)

 [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
 [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 10.3)
 [✓] iOS tools - develop for iOS devices
 [✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
 [✓] VS Code (version 1.37.1)
 [✓] Connected device (1 available)
```

pubspec.yaml packages:

```
 cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9+2
 dio: ^2.1.16
 firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
 firebase_core: ^0.4.0+9
 firebase_messaging: ^5.1.4
 firebase_storage: ^3.0.6
 flutter_facebook_login: ^2.0.1
 flutter_local_notifications: ^0.8.2
 flutter_webview_plugin: ^0.3.7
 google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.21
 google_maps_webservice: ^0.0.14
 google_places_picker: ^2.0.2+1
 google_sign_in: ^4.0.7
 geoflutterfire: ^2.0.3+5
 page_transition: ^1.1.4
 stripe_payment: ^0.2.1
```

How can I fix the startup crash?

Comment: Have a look at the _Android_ Logcat logs. Whenever an app crashes you'll find the cause there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the error logs thrown from the app when it crashed. If you the issue only occur after migrating to AndroidX, I suggest regenerating the Android build after updating the Flutter SDK that you're using. Run `flutter upgrade` then delete the `/android` build folder. Regenerate the android build by running `flutter create --platforms=android`, then run `flutter clean` and  `flutter pub get` to rebuild the indexes.